# PayPal hosted checkout page not showing paypal option

Tags: paypal, hosted

I am trying to create PayPal hosted pages (with PayPal Advanced). When I go to PayPal Manager -> Hosted Checkout Pages -> Customize, in the 'Preview', I am seeing only the 'Pay with Credit or Debit Card' option. I am not seeing the 'Pay with PayPal' option. Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some changes that you need to make to your PayPal Manager Hosted Checkout Pages.

1. In Hosted Checkout Pages Go to Setup
2. Scroll down to the Section Entitled **PayPal Express Checkout**
3. Next to **Enable PayPal Express Checkout:** choose **Yes** from the drop down
4. You can enable Bill Me Later as well by choosing **Yes** from the drop down
5. Scroll down to the bottom and click **save changes**

This will take effect immediately. 
Below is the link to PayPal's official Developer Site with additional information on integrating **PayPal Payments Advanced.**
[PayPal Payments Advanced Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-advanced)

Answer (score 1):

Though it's months ago, for anyone who'll might encounter this problem, It's because you have not set a PayPal Express checkout account when you created your PayFlow account. You have to set it so you can see "Enable PayPal Express Checkout" on your PayPal Manager Setup tab, or else, you will only see 'Pay with Credit or Debit Card' option in checkout process..

Comment: Thank-you! Months ago is my now :)