# PayPal hosted checkout page does not show paypal option

Tags: php, paypal, payflowlink

[PayPal hosted checkout page not showing paypal option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23099987/paypal-hosted-checkout-page-not-showing-paypal-option)

Sorry to double an existing question, but I'm really stuck here:

Hosted checkout page by paypal does not show paypal option. Service setting page at manager.paypal.com  does not seem to have an option to add express checkout or some other extra feature like that. I'm on PayFlow link in test mode. Test credit cards go through successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an option for PayPal in your Hosted Checkout pages, most likely that means that either you do not have a PayPal account associated with your test account or you do not have a PayPal Sandbox account associated.

From the PayPal Documentation, here is how to create a Sandbox Account:

With a Sandbox account, you can test PayPal products and services before you implement them on your website. You can see how everything works without having to exchange real money. You can also create test buyer accounts, see emails, and validate API credentials.

If you already have an existing PayPal account, signing up for a sandbox account is easy. Here's how:

1. Go to https://developer.paypal.com/.
2. Click Log In.
3. Enter your email address and PayPal password in the pop-up window and click Log In.
4. Click Applications at the top of the page.
5. Click Sandbox accounts.
6. Click Create Account.
7. Enter the required information, then click Create Account.

If you do not have an existing PayPal account, here's how to create a PayPal Sandbox account:

1. Go to https://developer.paypal.com/.
2. Click Sign Up Now.
3. Enter the required information, accept the Terms of Use and click Sign Up.
4. Wait a few minutes, then check your email for a message from PayPal.
5. Click the confirmation link in the email.

Note:

Sandbox test accounts are connected to your PayPal account login. 
No actual financial transactions take place on the test site. 
You can create test accounts with email addresses that aren't real.

Payflow Link can be setup to process payments with a third party processor other than PayPal. If you do not add a PayPal Sandbox email address or your confirmed PayPal Account email address, then you will not have the PayPal Option available. 
Here is an example of what it looks like in PayPal Manager:
[image]